# How to open a particular extension file from the email to my app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an attached file in my email. Now, once i will click on the attached file then it should open with my particular App install in my device. How can i achieve this? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add intent-filter to your manifest file to activity.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="file" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
</intent-filter>
```

And then in onCreate() in your activity check intent:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())){
    // use getData(), etc...
    String name = intent.getData().getPath();
}
```

You can check also [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html). It is for case when 3rd party app shares something with your app (not for "open with"), but it is similar and might help to understand in general how sharing/opening works.